# Spring Security (Without SpringBoot): Request is not being authenticated/authorized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I decided to explore Spring before getting into Spring Boot to understand how it all glues together at the foundation. I have a very basic `Security Config` set up to authenticate all the routes but it does not authorize or authenticate any of the paths/routes.

I even added a `custom filter (TenantFilter)` with a log statement in `doFilter()` to verify if the request is going down the `filter chain`. The log statement wasn't printed.

When the server starts up, the `SECURING IT` log within the `bean` declaration is printed which means the Security Chain Bean is being registered.

Dependencies: `spring-context (6.1.2)`, `spring-webmvc (6.1.2)`, `spring-security-config (6.1.2)`, `jakarta.servlet-api (6.1.0-M1)`, `spring-security-config (6.1.2)`, `spring-security-web (6.1.2)`

Container: `Tomcat 11`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
//@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/tryJsp").setViewName("index");
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder().username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SECURING IT");

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/app/*")).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/app/test")).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/*")).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("*/*")).authenticated()
        )
                //.addFilterBefore(new TenantFilter(), AuthorizationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Controller Mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getRoute(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    System.out.println("Request URL: " + requestURL); //prints http://localhost:8080/app/test
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    System.out.println("Request URI: " + requestURI); //prints  /app/test
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Yet another plain string response");
}
```

**Expectation**: Spring Security would block the request and show the default login form.

**Result**: When I hit the above route, I get a response back as `Yet another plain string response`. It doesn't ask me to log in.

Please help me understand if I am missing something. I have been following the book `Spring Start Here` + the Official Spring Doc for Spring Security setup (since many tutorials out there didn't work as expected, lacked details most of the time or were outdated).

Comment: @dur Yes. Thanks! I was able to figure it out. It was given in configurations sections later on in Spring Security but the filter chain bean registration part was given way before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working.

The problem was that I didn't declare a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`. This is required to register the `springSecurityFilterChain` for every URL in the application.

Ref: [Spring Doc For Java Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer)

Since I am using `Spring MVC` the `Configs` are already registered via `getServletConfigClasses()` of `WebApplicationInitializer`, even then the class `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` has to be extended for the security filter chain to work.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
//leave it empty

}
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java) for `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` explains a lot!